# Retrieve dataset from SQL stored procedure to C# using dataset and datatable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server, dataset

My stored procedure returns a dataset of 3 columns (emp id ,first name and last name).

I need to use `ExecuteSql()` with the dataset to display the records on a Dialog box using either Java script or jquery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013747/return-multiple-datasets-from-sql-server-stored-procedure/40014672 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344697/how-can-i-make-a-stored-procedure-return-a-dataset-using-a-parameter-i-pass

Comment: There are loads of tutorials out there which explain step by step how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return multiple datasets from sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013747/return-multiple-datasets-from-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_Name";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```