# Can't handle if reader.ReadDataTable() doesn't return any DATA from stored procedure in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database

I have created an API called `GetCustomerPrivacyStatus`, it is trying to find out the TandCstatus.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCustomerPrivacyStatus")]
public async Task<EULAInfo> GetCustomerPrivacyStatus()
{
    var result = new EULAInfo();

    string userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    var orgId = await GetOrgIdOfUser().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var TandCvalue = MasterDatabase.GetTermsAndConditionstatus(orgId).ToString();
    var TandCInt = TandCvalue != null ? TandCvalue : "0";
    var TandCstatus = Int16.Parse(TandCInt) == 0 ? false : true;
        
    result.status = TandCstatus;
        
    return result;
}
```

In the `GetTermsAndConditionstatus` it is calling a stored procedure, if the `orgId` is new that means it is not present is the database, that's why `dataTable.Rows[0]["TermsAndConditionAccepted"]` is throwing an error

> There is no row at position 0

I am not able to able to think how to resolve this situation.

```
public object GetTermsAndConditionstatus(string orgId)
{
    using (var reader = new StoredProcedureReader(this, "GetTermsAndConditionstatus", new { orgId }))
    {
        var dataTable = reader.ReadDataTable();
        var result = dataTable.Rows[0]["TermsAndConditionAccepted"] ;
            
        return result;
    }
}
```

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTermsAndConditionstatus]
    @orgId VARCHAR(100)
AS
    SELECT TermsAndConditionAccepted 
    FROM TermsAndConditionCheck 
    WHERE OrgId = @orgId
```

Is there is any way if there is no rows the result variable should be set to null?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! not sure what `StoredProcedureReader` does when calling stored procedure. this one might help to use which uses sql data adapters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344697/how-can-i-make-a-stored-procedure-return-a-dataset-using-a-parameter-i-pass

Comment: @coder_b : StoredProcedureReader  is kind of reading the stored procedure stored in the database in this specific case it is calling GetTermsAndConditionstatus Stored Procedure and passing orgId as a parameter

Comment: there are few things you could check, OrgId seems to be varchar, in your sql look like it is used as an int type, the other thing is if OrgId is a string need to wrap into single quotes. finally make sure the OrgId which you are passing existings in the TermsAndConditionCheck  table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
object result = null;

using (var reader = new StoredProcedureReader(this, "GetTermsAndConditionstatus", new { orgId }))
{
    var dataTable = reader.ReadDataTable();
   
    if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        result = dataTable.Rows[0]["TermsAndConditionAccepted"];   
}

return result;
```

That should fix your problem